# Will this portable DJ setup work?

Tags: setup

I'm looking to purchase a portable DJ Setup for my business, I'm targeting Pubs,Weddings(Halls), outdoor parties and occasionally small conferences. My setup will be based on powered speakers. It should be able to accommodate at least 200-300 people. I'm looking for something of quality but not too expensive. Please advise on what would be best speakers, thanks.

What I currently have:
Pioneer DJM-700
Pioneer CDJ-350s

Proposed speakers(all powered):

- 4 X 12" 200W Tops
- 1 X 15" 500W Sub

OR

- 4 X 15" 400W Tops

OR

- 2 X 12" 200W Tops
- 1 X 15" 500W Sub
- 2 X 15" 400W Tops

These are the speaker types I'm looking to choose from:

- 12in 200W Active Speaker with 2 Band EQ
- 15in 400W Active Speaker with 2 Band EQ
- 500W Powered Sub
- 15in 1400W Active Sub
- 18in Active 500W Bass Sub
- 12in 300W Active Speaker
- 15in 400W Active Speaker
- 10in 2-Way Active Loudspeaker
- 300W Active Speaker

Comment: We don't do product recommendations on Stack Exchange, so I have edited the question to make it answerable.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't aware.

Comment: No worries. Product recommendation questions just get closed as any answer may be an opinion or go out of date but I thought I'd make the question more broadly appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

From the list of speakers you have there, they could all be appropriate for the size of gigs you describe. You would be much better off with unpowered speakers though - if you use powered speakers you need to be able to plug them all in to the mains, and at many venues this can be a problem.

In general, a couple of subs (bigger can be better if your music has a lot of bass), couple of mids and a couple of tweeters can work for small venues like these, so the specific selection should not matter. PA speaker cabs usually have matched sets of speakers built in to the enclosure.

Of much more importance is the amp and mixer you plan to get, as you need a way to balance the signals to your speakers, as well as adjusting frequency gain.

My recommendation would be at a minimum a 4 channel mixer/amp with a built in graphic equaliser.

In terms of power, you should look at a couple of hundred watts. You won't need more than that unless you go to bigger venues. In terms of speakers, make sure they are rated higher than your amp - this reduces the likelihood of you blowing them up!

Comment: 80% of the time it will be House music. I guess I need to get at least one Sub and maybe 4 X 12" Mids